# adding alt text tags to slickR carousel in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, slickr

Colleagues and I are building a website in R-Markdown (basic, not blogdown, distillR, etc.) and have a couple slide carousels created using the slickR package. The code looks like:

```
library(slickR)

images <- c("Slide1.JPG", "Slide2.JPG", "Slide3.JPG", "Slide4.JPG", "Slide5.JPG")
test <- slickR(obj = images, height=350, width='100%') 
test
```

I have Googled around and cannot find a way to add alt text tags so that as you swipe from side to side you get text a screen reader can read.  Is this possible?  If so how?  Or, are there other ways to make the carousel accessible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following vignette for [slickR with DOMS](https://yonicd.github.io/slickR/articles/doms.html)

```r
library(slickR)

images <- c("Slide1.JPG", "Slide2.JPG", "Slide3.JPG", "Slide4.JPG", "Slide5.JPG")
imgs_bare <- mapply(function(x,txt){
  htmltools::tags$img(src = x, title = txt)
},x = nba_player_logo$uri[c(1:5)],txt = images,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
slickR(obj = imgs_bare, height=350)
```

Comment: Thank you yonicd!  Super helpful.  I was able to get this to work when my images were stored online and had a vector of URLs for x.  I had not put all of this together and really appreciate your work.